# How to replace the while loop with a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

// How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?
How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?
How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?How do you replace the while loop with for loop and produce the same result?
//

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class SubtractionQuizLoop {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 5; // Number of questions
    int correctCount = 0; // Count the number of correct answers
    int count = 0; // Count the number of questions
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String output = ""; // output string is initially empty
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {
      // 1. Generate two random single-digit integers
      int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

      // 2. If number1 < number2, swap number1 with number2
      if (number1 < number2) {
        int temp = number1;
        number1 = number2;
        number2 = temp;
      }

      // 3. Prompt the student to answer "What is number1 – number2?"
      System.out.print(
        "What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + "? ");
      int answer = input.nextInt();

      // 4. Grade the answer and display the result
      if (number1 - number2 == answer) {
        System.out.println("You are correct!\n");
        correctCount++;
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Your answer is wrong.\n" + number1 
          + " - " + number2 + " should be " + (number1 - number2) + "\n");

      // Increase the count
      count++;

      output += "\n" + number1 + "-" + number2 + "=" + answer + 
        ((number1 - number2 == answer) ? " correct" : " wrong");
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long testTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Correct count is " + correctCount + 
      "\nTest time is " + testTime / 1000 + " seconds\n" + output);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of regurgitating your question again and again please describe what you tried, what you know about the two loops, in which way your attempts failed. As is, your posts has a higher probability to annoy potential answereres than to get an answer.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help in order to get the first line of your code formatted correctly. Take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve your posts chances for helpful feedback.

Comment: You have used a `while` loop to basically count from 0 to just below `NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS`. What exactly keeps you from doing that with a `for` loop? Can that be fixed by following any tutorial on loops? Or with the help of the corresponding chapter in your text book?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; count++) {
  // your loop code
}
```

Using the for loop, you create a variable called `count`, and initialize it to 0. Then using `count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS`, you can exit this loop once count is equal to NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS. `count++` automatically increments the `count` value so you can remove the statement from your loop code.

And you will end up with something like:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; i++) {
          // 1. Generate two random single-digit integers
          int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    
          // 2. If number1 < number2, swap number1 with number2
          if (number1 < number2) {
            int temp = number1;
            number1 = number2;
            number2 = temp;
          }
    
          // 3. Prompt the student to answer "What is number1 – number2?"
          System.out.print(
            "What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + "? ");
          int answer = input.nextInt();
    
          // 4. Grade the answer and display the result
          if (number1 - number2 == answer) {
            System.out.println("You are correct!\n");
            correctCount++;
          }
          else
            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong.\n" + number1 
              + " - " + number2 + " should be " + (number1 - number2) + "\n");
    
          // Note that we do not use count++ here; it's moved to the for loop statement

          output += "\n" + number1 + "-" + number2 + "=" + answer + 
            ((number1 - number2 == answer) ? " correct" : " wrong");
        }
```